# my package.json file of react application shows different in file and different in vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-pages

I installed gh-pages for my react  project and ran into an error. I've shared an image which will make it clear. Due to that reason  I can't save my package.json file.[image]

Comment: Isn't it a git merge conflict which has to be resolved?

Comment: @Eugene I don't know, I'm new to gh-pages. How to resolve that conflict?

Comment: It's not about gh-pages. Maybe it's not git merge conflict, but visual studio code save conflict. As written here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47250 you should be able to edit right screen to change it as you want.